# Clearing up White Wolf World of Darkness tags

Tags: discussion, tags

There exists 4 tags for the White Wolf World of Darkness, specifically [nwod](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nwod), [world-of-darkness](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/world-of-darkness)/[wod](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wod) and the [storyteller-system](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/storyteller-system) and [storytelling-system](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/storytelling-system).

I've just edited the last two, to reflect the differences. But couldn't we clear it up a little? The two systems are so similarly named it's confusing.

thoughts?

Comment: Being barely familiar with the system, what would you suggest?  Which tags do we need?

Comment: @C.Ross This is my system of choice; I've got you covered. :)

Comment: Closing this in favor of the newest slobberknocker!

Answer (score 4):

Those tags serve the same distinct needs as the varied D&D edition tags do — they reflect different varieties and versions of the game and its attributed setting. I'm not a fan of the [nwod](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nwod) tag, as it's not official terminology, but here's what's intended.

[storyteller-system](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/storyteller-system) is for the mechanics of the classic World of Darkness games. (1991-2004; 2011–)
[storytelling-system](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/storytelling-system) is for the mechanics of the new World of Darkness games. (2005–)

[world-of-darkness](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/world-of-darkness) was intended to reflect elements of the setting of the games, but now has become a useful marker for the whole White Wolf WoD category, like [dungeons-and-dragons](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dungeons-and-dragons) is.

I can see a need for distinct settings tags for the old and new settings; I'd be interested to see what suggestions come up.

**Edited:** The comment thread causes me to suggest the following:

- [world-of-darkness](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/world-of-darkness) as the overcategory.
- [world-of-darkness-new](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/world-of-darkness-new) and [world-of-darkness-classic](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/world-of-darkness-classic) for the settings
- [storyteller-system-classic](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/storyteller-system-classic) and [storyteller-system-new](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/storyteller-system-new) for the systems, explaining that the proper name for "nWoD Storyteller" is "Storyte*lling*" as per White Wolf in the tag wiki. They could even be shortened to [storyteller-classic](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/storyteller-classic) and [storyteller-new](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/storyteller-new), if those were judged sufficiently clear.

Comment: so synonym `wod` to `world-of-darkness`?

Comment: That's already been done, I believe. It's on the synonym page.

Comment: Could we alter some of them for clarity? Or expanding on the tag wiki? As it stands someone not specifically aware of a difference will find [tag:storyteller-system] and [tag:storytelling-system] synonymous, which they aren't. Consider [tag:dnd-4e] and [tag:dnd3.5e], clearly different. I think it's important we make a distinction between oWoD and nWoD as the settings are different as well.

Comment: @Pureferret I think we can safely blame White Wolf for the confusing branding. :) The settings could be [tag:world-of-darkness-classic] and [tag:world-of-darkness-new], with [tag:oWoD] and [tag:nWoD] as synonyms. But the systems really do have separate names.

Comment: Then is there a way of making the system tags more distinct? See [here](http://meta.boardgames.stackexchange.com/q/645/2133) for a similar discussion about similar sounding board games.

Comment: @Pureferret By that solution, one answer would be to make the [tag:storytelling-system] tag into a [tag:storyteller-system-nwod] tag and explain that it's actually called the Storytelling System in the tag wiki.

Comment: I really like that solution.

Comment: I'd add cwod as a synonym for world-of-darkness-classic.  I've seen it used on rpg.net a fair amount already.

Comment: @mirv120 A fair point; that's what WW is calling it, too.