# is God Machine a good tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

A new tag: [god-machine](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/god-machine) has been created by xenoterracide.

This is distinct from [nwod-god-machine](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nwod-god-machine) because it about the setting element/entity/character known as the God-Machine.

Which while is a staple of the [nwod-god-machine](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nwod-god-machine) system,
is not intrinsically linked to it and plenty of games of [nwod-god-machine](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nwod-god-machine) 
are played without interacting with it.

And conversely games in other systems, such as nwod 1.0,  have been played with it,
there are published adventures,
and I personally have run a game (and I am sure I am not unique).

[This question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/10691/how-does-nwods-secret-history-the-god-machine-chapter-relate-to-the-other-cor/10700#10700) which is about nwod 1.0, deserves the tag (if we keep the tag),
so  I have added it.

**Are we in agreement that this is a valid tag?**

It is a bit like [rokugan](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rokugan) and [l5r](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/l5r).

Comment: I'm honestly not sure. We do have unusually specific tags like [[tag:wizard]], but we rarely do that for within-setting stuff. We don't have [elminster] or [the-great-wheel], for example.

Comment: Is there more than three questions that should have the tag?

Comment: I can think of a third: http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/44486/are-demons-able-to-effectively-deal-with-angels-in-the-twilight

Comment: I have no opinion, I just wanted to differentiate from the rule system because their is yet to be an `nwod-1` `nwod-2` tags. I think the answer would be the same as tagging `werewolf-the-forsaken` `the-pure`

Comment: @Oxinabox might also be worth asking is `god-machine` is intended to be as much of it's own game as `vampire-the-requiem` meaning will there be follow up books specific to the god machine

Comment: xenoterracide: I very much doubt we will see much more of the god machine in nwod-2.0, out side the the demon tag.
It might at most get a chapter or so in a splat each game line, maybe.
There are definately no upcoming plans (see http://theonyxpath.com/schedule/)  to make a pile of God Machine-line books. That is basically what Demon the Decent was/is.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Community Concensus seems to be that the tag is not good.
There have been no answers posted infavor of the tag,
And only 1 downvote on each answer ssupporting removing the tag.

I will delete it from the 2 questions it is on at the end of this week,
unless something changes.

Someone with the rep might like to make it an alias for [nwod-god-machine](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nwod-god-machine), in the future, but i doubt it, since the referring to the system that way will stop soon when the [rebranding to nWoD 2e happens, over the next few months.](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4773/lets-get-a-clear-consensus-on-the-use-of-nwod-vs-nwod-god-machine/4858#4858)

Possibly the time to review this will return to us in the future,
but by then a better name for the tag may also have come to us.

Answer (score 4):

We have very little precedent for pure "lore" tags that are smaller than a game setting. The few lore-ish tags that we do have are typically about mechanics or a mechanical context—[sr4-matrix](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sr4-matrix) and (arguably*) [feywild](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/feywild) come to mind.

Precedent aside, we don't have an unmet need for purely lore tags more granular than a setting either—a setting tag and asking their question in the body is plenty to identify what they're talking about, both for users, SEO, and searchability. We don't need to collect together all information on [drizzt](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/drizzt) or [gandalf](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gandalf) for browse-ability, and neither do we for the God Machine.

Rather than remove or burninate it, we can use it as a synonym for the God Machine / NWoD 2e system—it will be mistakenly used as a one anyway.

<sup>* The [feywild](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/feywild) tag has only four questions, and it looks like it isn't actually useful on three of those, and questionable on the fourth. It may be worth killing off too.</sup>

Comment: I do not agree with this on the principle that the god machine, it's infrastructure, and angels feel... more vast than just the core rules.

Comment: @xenoterracide But to us, it's just a setting detail in an RPG. It's tiny in our world and the game(s) itself is vastly more important.

Answer (score 3):

It's almost certainly going to get misused as if it was [nwod-god-machine](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nwod-god-machine) instead. The name is just too similar and doesn't do anything to distinguish what it's for. The tag wiki description does do that, but we all know people will use it without reading that.

Then we've got [nwod](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nwod). So we've now created a situation where a question tagged [nwod](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nwod)[god-machine](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/god-machine) is a fundamentally different thing than one tagged [nwod-god-machine](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nwod-god-machine). I find that more confusing than it was before, when the intention was to make it clearer.

Also, is Google going to understand the difference between them, or are we going to muck up search results in this case?

IMO, I'd call the tag something like [the-god-machine](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-god-machine) (just to throw out an example, there's probably a better name), which makes it's intended use more obvious. While it's impossible to totally prevent misunderstandings, we should try to be clear and obvious with the tag purpose when possible.

Comment: Perhaps it is because I'm not familiar with the setting, but why is it even necessary to have two separate tags, one for the system as a whole and one for the setting the system is associated with? Is it the case that there are multiple settings associated with it? If the answer to the last question is no then I would say the setting tag is unnecessary

Comment: the tag god machine isn't for the setting, it is for a particular Entity within the setting, thus adding godmachine-setting would be confusing.
The tag nwod-god-machine is (probably) going to be replaced with nwod-2.0, i believe, see: http://meta.rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/4773/lets-get-a-clear-consensus-on-the-use-of-nwod-vs-nwod-god-machine?rq=1

Comment: @Phil It may not be, but there is precident for it in the world-of-darkness tag, which is the setting tag for game tags like vampire-the-masquerade (although it's also used as a broader system tag in some cases). The White Wolf tags are nothing if not confusing.

Comment: The wod tags are indeed confusing, which is why I am ever watching the tagging new nwod-god-machine questions. Which is why i noticed this new tag appearing. (I can't fix the overall wod tagging problem, but i can maybe keep this little corner sane if i try :-P)

Comment: @Oxinabox As I said, the name was just something I came up with as an example. Someone can probably do better, particlarly since I woke up 20 minutes ago. :) But as the tags stand right now, god-machine is a really lousy name when paired with nwod on a question.

Comment: Maybe you could change it to `the-god-machine` or `god-machine-entity` ?

Comment: @GMNoob Thanks! Edited.

Answer (score 2):

It seems odd to me. The analogy would be having a [cthulhu](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cthulhu) that was separate from [call-of-cthulhu](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/call-of-cthulhu) or any particular Lovecraftian game. More specifically, since the God Machine exists in only one game line, it'd be like having a tag for a specific D&D deity.

Comment: I actually think a cthulu / Call-of-cthulu tag has alot of virtue, compared to God Machine.
And indeed we *do* have a distinct cthulu tag.

Comment: So we do. Most of the questions tagged with it shouldn't be, though, as they don't actually mention or reference the Elder God. Maybe turn it into cthulhu-mythos?

Comment: That is for another meta question (though I think i agree)

Comment: @Oxinabox Done.

Comment: though the comparison mentioned here is relevant since when I created the tag, I also included the god machines angels and infrastructure, and basically etc as part of it.