# Synonym [nwod-god-machine] to [new-world-of-darkness-2e]

Tags: support, status-completed, tags, world-of-darkness

As discussed in [Lets get a clear consensus on the use of [nwod] vs [nwod-god-machine]](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4773/lets-get-a-clear-consensus-on-the-use-of-nwod-vs-nwod-god-machine/4858#4858),
now that Onyx Path has [officially rebranded the *God Machine Rules Update* as the second edition of *New World of Darkness*](http://theonyxpath.com/the-world-of-darkness-second-edition/), we should go ahead and replace and synonym all our [nwod-god-machine](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nwod-god-machine) tags to [new-world-of-darkness-2e](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/new-world-of-darkness-2e).

Agreement seems to have been generally reach on the aforementioned thread that we should rename the tag, so this is just a request for mod tools support. There are currently 71 questions tagged with [nwod-god-machine](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nwod-god-machine), making manual retagging possible but not ideal.

**I believe there is a moderator tool to rename tags.
Can that be used please?**

Comment: since this question is the first time I've heard of nwod-2e, wouldn't it be better to synonymize the two tags?

Comment: @gatherer818: See updated question

Comment: makes sense to me ^_^

Comment: @thedarkwanderer It's already been discussed; this is just a request for implementation of the consensus already arrived at.

Comment: OK, synonym and merge done from nwod-god-machine to new-world-of-darkness-2e

Comment: YAAAAAAY. The aesthetics of that name as an "edition" tag were terrible.