# Tag synonym request: [storytelling-system] - > [nwod]

Tags: support, status-completed, tags

The [storytelling-system](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/storytelling-system) tag is a relic from a much earlier idea of WoD tagging; there never were any games that used the Storytelling system that were not also [nwod](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nwod) games, and with the subsequent developments involving Onyx Path, there won't be. Let's bring together that which once was asunder.

Edit: [synonym created](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/tags/nwod/synonyms); those with enough rep should vote.

Answer (score 2):

Seems like a good idea,

We do not have enough questions that would justerfy considering the system's theoretical generic base, that only has one game for it, separately from that one game.

There are almost no used that are not also uses of [nwod](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nwod).

I am a few hundred rep from that required to create synonyms.
But if you do that, then those of use with more than 5 tag repm
can go [vote for making the synonym.](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/tags/nwod/synonyms).

There are enough people with enough rep to solve it democratically in the synonym system, I believe.

Comment: I'm concerned about confusion between it and the storyteller system - we also have stuff tagged storyteller system (the core system for oWoD) but there's various that are not tagged correctly using that distinction (e.g. http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/10348/does-killing-an-enemy-in-combat-count-against-morality-in-world-of-darkness) - post synonym I suspect there will be things incorrectly tagged nWoD.

Comment: There won't be that many, afterall there are only 12 questions tagged storytelling. It will infact be easier to fix as it will be obvious that they are not nwod and so we can solve through normal process.

Comment: 25, if we're using the same search.

Comment: my mistake, I must have misremembered.
Still not many. So even if 1/4 of all uses of the tag are wrong that is only 6 questions to fix.
And fixing mistakes is a end in and of itself.

Comment: OK - how about y'all review and fix the storytelling-system q's (25) and the storyteller-system Q's (9) and then I'll synonym and merge?

Comment: Ok, just did that. The only mistagging I  could find was the one you linked.
There is the case of http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/6735/how-to-use-intelligence-in-scion.
I need to look at my Sion rulebook to see if it is actually storyteller. I haven't played it, but I heard it was not rules identical to owod, or nwod.

Comment: "Scion uses a rules system similar to the Storyteller system made popular by the World of Darkness, but is not part of the World of Darkness. The rules are a new version of the system presented in Exalted: Second Edition but set in a modern world, that also includes elements from the Trinity Universe series of games, most notably Aberrant."  I'd say "none of the above."

Comment: But i would like to check the book. If it is labelled "Uses the Storyteller system." Then who are we to argue? (Answer: Better informed than the publishers who do not have as much hindsight)

Comment: Not really relevant since it won't make a lot of sense to tag it world-of-darkness - this is one of the fringe cases where getting rid of these system tags is a problem and we'll have to live with it.  The other two Scion questions are just tagged Scion.

Answer (score 2):

I have synonymed storytelling-system to nwod and storyteller-system to world-of-darkness.