# Cleaning up the Mess of cleaning up the mess of wod tag metas

Tags: support, status-completed, meta, duplicates

There are 3 meta questions about clearing up the mess of WoD Tags.

- [Shall we review the various World of Darkness tags' use?](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2880/shall-we-review-the-various-world-of-darkness-tags-use)
- [Clearing up White Wolf World of Darkness tags](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1189/clearing-up-white-wolf-world-of-darkness-tags)
- [Clean up tagging for "World of Darkness" related questions](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4933/tagging-mess-that-is-world-of-darkness)

These are Duplicates, we would not allow this on the mainsite, can we stop doing it/fix it on meta? It is even more confusing here.
and actively contributing to the problems all 3 try to fix

I think they need to be merged,
or the older ones locked, and linked ot the newer one.

None have been implemented cleanly.
even the ones that got concesus.
Some act actively contradicted by future more focused metas.
like: [Tag synonym request: [storytelling-system] - > [nwod]](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4958/tag-synonym-request-storytelling-system-nwod)

Answer (score 2):

Yes!  No!  I don't know!

So is this supposed to be the new question?  Or are you proposing "there should be a new question?" So... sure?  We could close all the existing ones as status-declined and let y'all start afresh... I'm willing to watch this spiral into infinity, since I don't get compensated to mod the site I guess I can interpret that as working by the hour...

Done!  I've closed the old 2 as dupes of the new one. May the God-Machine have mercy on your souls.

Comment: No, this it not supposed to be the new question. that would add a 4th question to the mix.