# World of Darkness tags: include the 'the' from the title, or drop it?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

There's a discrepancy in our World of Darkness tags. [As you can (presently) see here](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5005/1204), the vast majority skip any 'the' that is present, whether it's from OWOD — [vampire-masquerade](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vampire-masquerade), [werewolf-apocalypse](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/werewolf-apocalypse), [mage-ascension](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mage-ascension) — or NWOD — [mage-awakening](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mage-awakening), [changeling-lost](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/changeling-lost), [hunter-vigil](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hunter-vigil).

But these two have it: [promethean-the-created](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/promethean-the-created) and [demon-the-descent](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/demon-the-descent).

I figure rather than obliterating and renaming those last two to fit the majority, I'd ask here: do we want our tag naming scheme to include the *'the'* in the game titles, or should we skip it?

On one hand, the *'the'* adds a little bit of legibility and, in my opinion, looks a little nicer. On the other hand, it eats up ~4 characters, though we can skip it for games that desperately need those characters. Neither its inclusion nor omission is strictly necessary.

Which one should we go with?

*(Hopefully this won't have to be settled by breaking a pool cue in half and waiting for the last one standing.)*

Comment: Shouldn't this be in the big retagging thread?

Comment: I figured it was more appropriate in its own question where it could canvass answers, and not just binary votes and comments. I've linked to it from there.

Comment: I think PtC has the longest title, so is this 4 character thing actually a thing? (other than that, no opinion, I created PtC, it seemed more natural to type it out and I didn't think 'bout it)

Comment: @xenoterracide Tags have a limit of 25 characters, so 4 characters _can_ be a concern. I don't think it is here, though. [promethean-the-created] sits at 22 characters, which means it still has room for the 3 characters it takes to add '-2e' to the end if a second edition comes out. Even [new-world-of-darkness] (21 chars) is fine. [[tag:vampire-kindred-of-east]] (23 chars) seems to be the only WoD tag that would pass the 25 character limit if written in full.

Comment: I have synonym/merged all the stuff to "the"s as far as I can tell, and did the kindred change suggested below.

Comment: @mxyzplk Thanks! The following still need them: [wraith-oblivion], [geist-sin-eaters]

Comment: Did those too now.

Comment: @mxyzplk Thanks for doing the work involved in those renames.

Answer (score 5):

**Use full titles**

I agree with the notion that having the "the" in there increases readability, and I can't think of any reason to not include it, unless it doesn't fit the character limit. doppelgreener pointed out in the comments, that

> [promethean-the-created](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/promethean-the-created) sits at 22 characters, which means it still has room for the 3 characters it takes to add '-2e' to the end if a second edition comes out. [...] [vampire-kindred-of-east](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vampire-kindred-of-east) (23 chars) seems to be the only WoD tag that would pass the 25 character limit if written in full.

So the only WoD product that has more than 25 characters (including whitespace, excluding punctuation) is [**Kindred of the East**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kindred_of_the_East). Incidentally, I noticed that it is called just that, rather than **Vampire: Kindred of the East**. Renaming this particular tag to not include "Vampire" will allow for a "the".

If you feel that "Vampire" is needed for tag visibility, I suggest making [vampire-kindred-of-east](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vampire-kindred-of-east) a Synonym of [kindred-of-the-east](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kindred-of-the-east) instead.

Comment: Yeah, this is standard policy. We should tag according to actual titles as used, rather than abbreviations that are idiosyncratic to RPG.SE. The tag for *Kindred of the East* should definitely be fixed to actually say its name, and having the tag synonym will catch anyone who mistakenly thinks it has "Vampire: " in the title.