# Changing [new-world-of-darkness-2e] to [chronicles-of-darkness]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, world-of-darkness

Gosh, it's been a bit since we had a WoD tagging thread, huh? As per today's announcement, the game lines formerly known as the New World of Darkness 2nd Edition are now being collectively called the Chronicles of Darkness.

http://theonyxpath.com/announcing-chronicles-of-darkness/

Reasons why are in the link. What's the best way to go forward? (I mean, aside from updating the tag wiki and such.)

Comment: [tag:chronicles-of-darkness] is starting to get used, three questions as of that time >

Comment: I used it to indicate 2nd edition back then as it was not sure if Onyxpath only labeled 2nd edition like that or if it labeled both editions now as that.

Answer (score 12):

One way forward:

[old-world-of-darkness](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/old-world-of-darkness) goes to [world-of-darkness](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/world-of-darkness) — the way it was all the way back.

[new-world-of-darkness-2e](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/new-world-of-darkness-2e) goes to [chronicles-of-darkness](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/chronicles-of-darkness).

[new-world-of-darkness](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/new-world-of-darkness) stays [new-world-of-darkness](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/new-world-of-darkness), since those books won't be rebranded and people will be searching for them under that name. The fact that these books are the historical antecedents of the CofD books remains a hiccup.

Comment: This makes the most sense, to me at least.

Comment: @Ahriman Partly because the publishers are reverting to calling oWoD just “WoD”. Assuming the RPG community in general adopts the terminology and starts using WoD and CoW, our tags should match that usage. (It avoids our tags from being confusing and conflicting with standard usage.)

Comment: I am... skeptical of not retagging first edition nWoD... I think it will lead to confusion.  That said this name change is less than 24 hours old.

Comment: I was thinking the same as @Tritium21. Perhaps [new-world-of-darkness-1e], either as a synonym (for discoverability) or as the master tag (for unambiguity at the cost of being slightly off community usage)?

Comment: @SevenSidedDie I am worried that we could make some good sounding decisions that don't play out.  For example, if the community considered CofD to be a '2e', then we can unambiguously create a lot of aliases (CofD<->CofD2e<->nWoD2e, nWoD1e<->CofD1e, etc)... if it doesn't, then it would only make things worse.

Comment: @Tritium21 There's no rush. Also, for that kind of concern, we only really need to get the master tag right—synonyms are easy to create or remove.

Comment: Since [world-of-darkness] will become specific to OWOD with this scheme, if/when we ever need a tag for the whole series we can just use something like [world-of-darkness-series] (24 char).

Comment: @doppelgreener I...don't actually see that being that much of an issue.  As it stands there are questions with both nWoD and oWoD tags... mostly for the conversion docs.  Other uses of the two in the same question is most often a mistake that gets edited away.

Comment: Is there a consensus on this?

Comment: The "old" & "new" labels were widely used in the community, but typically absent from the published material. (Indeed, a search for "new world" in the nWoD core yields no result). They were officially "Classic World of Darkness" (technically destroyed by Gehenna et al.) & "World of Darkness" (meant at first to fully replace oWoD). It confused many & stifled the brand (see link in the Q), thus this change.

I disagree with nWoD remaining its own tag, as Chronicles is officially 1 game with 2 eds; nWoD being a synonym for 1e makes some sense, as community references to that may always exist.

Comment: By "goes to" you mean becomes an synonym, right? Or do you mean a full rename?

Comment: @Oxinabox "Becomes" — as in, the things currently tagged [old-world-of-darkness] would now be tagged [world-of-darkness], with the former as a synonym.

Comment: Got it. I agree. This would be best. I am getting fairly tired of Onyx Path/Whitewolf/CCTP/Paradox renaming things. They have good reason, but they don't seem to be thinking about the costs in terms of fracturing/confounding the fanbase. Anyway that is off topic. And tag wikis to clarify things.
It's a good thing we have synonyms to handle more or less exactly this.

Answer (score 9):

> [old-world-of-darkness](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/old-world-of-darkness) goes to [world-of-darkness](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/world-of-darkness) — the way it was all the way back. (Jadasc's answer)

We really should make [new-world-of-darkness](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/new-world-of-darkness) an alias for [chronicles-of-darkness](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/chronicles-of-darkness). The [Onyx Path forums](http://forum.theonyxpath.com) have entirely renamed what was the New World of Darkness to Chronicles of Darkness.  They don't yet seem to have a distinction between first edition and second edition, but I think we will want that distinction.

I propose [chronicles-of-darkness-1e](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/chronicles-of-darkness-1e) and [chronicles-of-darkness-2e](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/chronicles-of-darkness-2e) as well (with relevant short aliases).

Comment: I agree with this approach the most. It seems clear to me that Onyx Path and White Wolf intend for all instances of nWoD to simply become Chronicles of Darkness, regardless of 1e or 2e. Unlike many other tabletop edition changes, Onyx Path has stated that 2e is not intended to invalidate 1e books (http://theonyxpath.com/the-world-of-darkness-second-edition/) and, indeed, VtR 2e recommends 1e books such as the clan books and Damnation City. (see VtR2e p. 9)

Comment: +1 here as Rich (as tritium21 citated) said thet nwod is now chronicles of darkness and with the need to differentate between both editions (as the books for each splat are named the same each....forsaken used as tag for both 1st and 2nd edition most of the time so far) I think it would be easiest to put 1e and 2e there (and most fitting to the rename as a whole)

Answer (score 7):

It should be noted that the official stance of Onyx Path (and by virtue of being the only mouthpiece I can find for the new White Wolf, presumably White Wolf), that 'New World of Darkness' branding is being retroactively sunset.

[A commenter asked](http://theonyxpath.com/2015-heres-how-we-rolled-monday-meeting-notes/#comment-455090)...

> Minor request when you have a chance, can you clarify the naming conventions on the Chronicles as far as how they relate to the nWoD versions? Is it only nWoD 2 that is the Chronicles and the old version is still nWoD, is it Chronicles 1 and 2nd Ed, or is it something else all together?

To which Rich Thomas (richt), head of Onyx, replied

> All of the stuff we have previously or would call nWoD is now Chronicles of Darkness.

By official naming, all the [new-world-of-darkness](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/new-world-of-darkness) and similarly named tags should be transitioned to [chronicles-of-darkness](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/chronicles-of-darkness) and similarly named tags *if we are going to encourage following the official product names* - which is admittedly complicated by not being the name on some of the book covers.

Answer (score 4):

The following merger and rearrangement has been performed:

- [new-world-of-darkness](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/new-world-of-darkness) → **[chronicles-of-darkness-1e](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/chronicles-of-darkness-1e)**

  Synonyms are [new-world-of-darkness-1e](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/new-world-of-darkness-1e), [storytelling-system](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/storytelling-system), [nwod-1e](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nwod-1e)
- [new-world-of-darkness-2e](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/new-world-of-darkness-2e) → **[chronicles-of-darkness-2e](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/chronicles-of-darkness-2e)**

  Synonyms are [new-world-of-darkness-2e](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/new-world-of-darkness-2e), [nwod-god-machine](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nwod-god-machine)

  The few questions previously tagged [chronicles-of-darkness](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/chronicles-of-darkness) were also merged into [chronicles-of-darkness-2e](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/chronicles-of-darkness-2e) to preserve their correct edition tagging.
- [old-world-of-darkness](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/old-world-of-darkness) → **[world-of-darkness](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/world-of-darkness)**

  Synonyms are [old-world-of-darkness](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/old-world-of-darkness), [storyteller-system](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/storyteller-system), [owod](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/owod), [wod-20th-anniversary](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wod-20th-anniversary), [cwod](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cwod), [classic-world-of-darkness](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/classic-world-of-darkness), [wod](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wod)

There are now no [new-world-of-darkness](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/new-world-of-darkness) or [nwod](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nwod) tags, nor a [chronicles-of-darkness](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/chronicles-of-darkness) tag. They are also not tag synonyms, as that would encourage inaccurate tagging (i.e., when different askers assume the lack of edition marker means “current” and others assume it means 1st edition). Askers typing any will be presented with the CoD 1e and 2e tags and under normal circumstances will be prompted to make the choice between them. (If the tags get recreated and question clarification fails to keep them non-existent, we may need to revisit this.)

The tag wikis have been minimally updated to reflect the changes.

One notable wiki change: the tag wikis no longer recommend a “setting” tag be used for pan-edition questions — such questions were formerly officially advised to use [world-of-darkness](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/world-of-darkness), but that was never actually done in practice and the tag was empty before the rearrangement was done. There is now currently no “setting” tag for the old or new WoD — setting questions should use the game being played instead, or multiple where overlap is involved. (This is consistent with our tagging practices for games with tight binding between setting and rules editions.)

On that note, our major *(W)oD tagging guidance on meta is now obsolete (formerly contained in [Lets get a clear consensus on the use of [nwod] vs [nwod-god-machine]](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4773/lets-get-a-clear-consensus-on-the-use-of-nwod-vs-nwod-god-machine)). Tagging guidance should either be redone in a meta post or (more ideally) be clearly presented in the three tags' wikis. Minimal guidance has been added in a **Related tags** section of the three tags' wikis.